# Как удалить класс у предыдущих сестринских элементов?

Tags: jquery

Есть структура:

```
<div class="view-source" rel="1"> </div>
<div class="view-source" rel="2"> </div>
<div class="view-source" rel="3"> </div>
<div class="view-source" rel="4"> </div>
```

Сейчас по клику на `view-source` добавляется/удаляется класс `toggleClass`.

Можно ли как-то при добавлении удалять все классы, находящиеся выше, например, `rel=4`. Т.е. при клике на `rel=4` добавляется класс этому блоку, но при этом если этот класс уже есть в `rel=1 || rel=2 || rel=3` его оттуда удалить.

Comment: а если клик по третьему?

Comment: удалится все что выше. Т.е. 1 и 2 блоки останутся без класса, а третий с классом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) можно найти все предыдущие сестринские элементы.

```js
$('.view-source').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggleClass').prevAll('.view-source').removeClass('toggleClass');
});
```

```css
.view-source {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}
.view-source + .view-source {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.view-source.toggleClass {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-source toggleClass" rel="1"> </div>
<div class="view-source toggleClass" rel="2"> </div>
<div class="view-source" rel="3"> </div>
<div class="view-source" rel="4"> </div>
```

Comment: спасибо! То что искал. Однако, проблему мою это не решило. Получается, копал не в ту сторону.

Comment: @DmitryN если это решило проблему, описанную в вопросе, пожалуйста, отметьте ответ верным

Comment: @VenZell видимо он имел в виду `$(this).toggleClass('.view-source').prevAll('.view-source').removeClass('.view-source');`

Comment: @Jean-Claude, восстановите ответ и исправьте этот момент, я поставлю вам плюс за альтернативное решение

Comment: @VenZell оки, сделал

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне решить мою проблему!

Answer (score 3):

Ну например так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.rows > div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('view-source').prevAll().removeClass();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.view-source {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="" rel="1">1</div>
  <div class="" rel="2">2</div>
  <div class="" rel="3">3</div>
  <div class="" rel="4">4</div>
</div>
```